# python: convenient way to create list of strings of repeated elements

Tags: python

How can I create a list like this:

```
["a","a","a",... (repeating "a" a hundred times") "b","b","b",(repeating "b" a hundred times.. )]
```

If I write `["a","b"] * 100`, then I get `["a","b","a","b",...]`, which is not exactly what I want.

Is there any function as simple as this one but gives me the result I want?

Comment: `['a'] * 100 + ['b'] * 100`

Comment: Check also `itertools.repeat` if you want the values to be obtained lazily, as in: `chain(repeat('a', 100), repeat('b', 100))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

```
>>> [x for x in ['a', 'b'] for y in range(100)]
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', ..., 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', ...]
```

Answer (score 5):

Just sum two lists produced by multiplication first and second elements:

```
['a']*100 + ['b']*100
```

It's faster than list comprehension and sort:

```
python -m timeit "sorted(['a', 'b']*100)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.76 usec per loop

python -m timeit "[x for x in ['a', 'b'] for y in range(100)]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.15 usec per loop

python -m timeit "['a']*100 + ['b']*100"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.86 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sak = ['a','b','c','d']
list = sak*100
print sorted(list)
```

---

```
var = ['a','b']
list = sorted(var*100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import repeat

list(repeat('a',100)) +  list(repeat('b',100))
```